# JSF f:ajax and IE 8

Tags: java, jsf-2

I encountered with problem: in IE8 don't work event in f:ajax and don't update other components after change value.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="someId"
                        value="#{someBean.showEmpty}"
                        title="#{i18n['button.showEmpty']}">
                        <f:ajax event="change"
                            listener="#{someBean.changeShowEmpty}"
                            execute=":someForm @form" render=":messages :someForm @form" />
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

In Chrome, Opera, Firefox - it works.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's indeed "expected" behaviour for MSIE. It will only work on 2nd change and forth, because MSIE thinks that the 1st click is in essence not a change. You should be listening on the `click` event instead. That's also exactly what the `<f:ajax>` **already by default** does for a `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`. Just remove the `event` attribute altogether.

```html
<f:ajax listener="#{someBean.changeShowEmpty}"
    execute=":someForm @form" render=":messages :someForm @form" />
```

The `<f:ajax event>` defaults to `"valueChange"` in `UIInput` components and defaults to `"action"` in `UICommand` components. In `UIInput` components which generate radio button or checkbox, it will then generate `onclick`. In other `UIInput` components (text fields, textarea, dropdowns, etc) it will generate `onchange`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, an other `<h:form>` can **not** be processed in contrary to what you seem to think in `execute` attribute, simply because its values are not submitted along with the submit of the current form. But that's another story.